# Изменение padding-bottom у div элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема в следующем:

Имеется div элемент, который автоматически создается. Выглядит следующим образом:

[image: div]

Есть ли какая возможность изменить у этого элемента padding-bottom с помощью JS?
Как можно к нему обратиться, если ни класса, ни айди у этого элемента нет.

**UPD:** Данный блок лежит в:

```
 <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">

            <div Нужный блок>

        </div> ...
```

**UPD2:**

Смог добраться до нужного элемента следующим образом:

```
document.querySelector( "div.form-row" )
.parentNode.querySelector("div:nth-child(2)")
.querySelector("div")
```

Вопрос: Можно ли как то упростить данное выражение и как установить **.css("padding-bottom: 0em;")**? просто при вызове

```
document.querySelector( "div.form-row" )
.parentNode.querySelector("div:nth-child(2)")
.querySelector("div").css("padding-bottom: 0em;")
```

Пишет, что css не является функцией.

Comment: у этого блока есть же родитель ?

Comment: @MaximLensky , ответ на Ваш вопрос добавил в описание

Comment: ну тогда parentNode.querySelector("div:nth-child(3)") по моему так

Comment: Вы его создаёте, блок этот?

Comment: @InDevX, блок div создается автоматически, библиотекой JS для автодополнения текста.

Comment: создайте лучше ему обёртку и ищите по ней, меньше гемора будет

Comment: @MaximLensky, возможно так, но просто в консоли хрома пишет, что не может определить метод querySelector для this.parentNode

Comment: @InDevX данный div вешается на input поле. Поверх него. Выше этого дива <div class="col-3">, которому я могу присвоить id, вопрос только в том, что делать дальше?

Comment: если это единственный блок с такими стилями то можно как-то так сделать `let a = document.querySelector('div').style.position, b = document.querySelector('div').style.paddingBottom; if ( a&&b && (a=='relative'&&b=='1rem')){ b = '0rem'; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

при помощи JQuery можно так

```
$('.col-3 div').css('padding-bottom','')
```

Comment: Валерий, а как корректно обратиться, если у .col-3 есть id? чтобы применилось не ко всем дивам с классом .col-3

Comment: @МишаковАлександр `$('#id.col-3 div')`

Comment: @InDevX, Да, спасибо! Попробавл сначала так, но неправильное значение указал в атрибутах и подумал, что так нельзя. Потом заработало. Хотел удалить коммент.

Comment: без jquery -> `document.getElementById("id").getElementsByClassName("col-3")[0].style.paddingBottom='0rem';`

Comment: @МишаковАлександр на нативном js проще же

Comment: @MaximLensky, я бэкэнд разработчик и с фронтедом знаком на ВЫ. Верстаю из того, что нашел))

Comment: @МишаковАлександр вертайте без jQuery хотя я не враг ему но на js не надо эту библиотеку

Answer (score 1):

Вот реализация на js

```js
[...document.querySelector(".form-row").children][2].style.paddingBottom = '0' + "px";
```

```html
<style>
  .col-2,
  .col-3 {
    background: yellow;
  }
  
  .form-row div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: lightblue;
  }
</style>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-2">col-2</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 1em;">нужный блок</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А почему Вы против использование jQuery?

Comment: @МишаковАлександр я не против но если можно избежать его использование то надо избегать тем более что большенство щас применяют vue, react то jquery не в почёте просто ..

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет!

Comment: @МишаковАлександр если где там на сервере отвалится jquery то он просто перестанет работать со всеми слайдерами и прочими плюшками а ведь js на прямую исполняется в браузере а для jquery нужен компилятор в виде библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

Ну и в конце концов на чистом css без javascript и jquery

```css
.col-2,
.col-3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.form-row div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: lightblue;
  padding-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-2">col-2</div>
  <div class="col-3">col-3</div>
  <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 1em;">нужный блок</div>
</div>
```